# PHP Regex Dealing With Parenthesis

Tags: regex

As far as i understand regex tries to match everything mentioned in brackets

eg.

```
<b>(.*)</b>
```

Inside a larger regular expressions how do u differentiate between this and the braces mentioned in the regular expression to be matched.

```
(hello),(how)
```

in the above example we need to match brackets, but if the reg exp itself has paranthesis [as in first example] then how will it be differentiated?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match literal `()`, then you need to escape them in most `regex` engines, like this: `\(`, `\)`.

Comment: Can u explain by writing a regular expression for the example in my question?? ( which can b used by preg_match In php)

Comment: @Aamir, What exactly are you trying to capture? The stuff between the literal parenthesis? Including the literal parenthesis, or not including the literal parenthesis?

Comment: tried out a few regular expressions and i understood now ... thanks for ur help